# Make cut-off corners with a border

Tags: html, css, shapes, css-shapes

I want to make a shape in html that has cutoff corners and with a borderline around the shape.

I can make cut-off shapes without a border like so:

html:

```
<div class="cut-off"></div>
```

css:

```
 .cut-off{
   position:relative;
   top:400px;
   left:400px;
   height:155px;
   width:200px;
   background:red;
}
.cut-off:after{
   position:absolute;
   bottom:0px; right:-20px;
   content:".";
   text-indent:-999px; overflow:hidden;
   display:block;
   width:0px; height:0px;
   border-top: 20px solid green;
   border-right: 20px solid transparent;
}
.cut-off:before{
   position:absolute;
   top:0; right:-20px;
   content:"#";
   text-indent:-999px; overflow:hidden;
   display:block;
   background:blue;
   width:20px; height:135px;
}
```

[Jfiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/KR3XK/)

Now i want a border that goes around the shape. 
How should i do that?

I want a shape that is something like this:

[image: shape]

Filled with a color.

Comment: good question...gonna be tough and you'll probably need to use css transformations to make that last diagonal line..i did this much though: http://jsfiddle.net/KR3XK/2/

Comment: And can you show a picture of how you want it to look?

Answer (score 3):

By altering your html structure a little bit, I could make [this](http://jsfiddle.net/KR3XK/13/)

```
<div class="cut-off"></div>
<div class="cut-off2"></div>​


.cut-off{
position: relative;
width: 300px;
height: 150px;
border-bottom: 80px red solid;
border-right: 80px transparent solid;
}

.cut-off2{
position: absolute;
z-index: -1;
top:0;
left: 0;
width: 305px;
height: 150px;
border-bottom: 82px blue solid;
border-right: 80px transparent solid;
}

p{
position: absolute;
left: 0;
bottom:-40px;

}
```

​

Basically it adds another div under the existing one. For the cuttof effect it plays with border dimensions.

EDIT: I also provided a way of including content in the area.

Answer (score 0):

Try this out:

```
<div class="cut-off">content</div>​​​​​​​​​​​
.cut-off{
   position:relative;
   height:155px;
   width:200px;
   background:red;
}
.cut-off:after{
   position:absolute;
   bottom:0px; right:-20px;
   content:".";
   text-indent:-999px; overflow:hidden;
   display:block;
   width:0px; height:0px;
   border-top: 20px solid green;
   border-right: 20px solid transparent;
}
.cut-off:before{
   position:absolute;
   top:0; right:-20px;
   content:"#";
   text-indent:-999px; overflow:hidden;
   display:block;
   background:blue;
   width:20px; height:135px;
}
```

By the way, I found this example in the following page (and therefore I do not claim that the code is mine): http://www.wahnbriefe.net/web-design/css-cut-off-corners

Comment: Iam sorry that is exacly the same what i already had. See my jfiddle. I want that shape with a border around that.

Comment: Apologies. I didn't notice it

Answer (score -1):

I'm not really sure if this is what you're looking for, but I think you could use the CCS3 border-radius attribute in order to achieve it. Perhaps it is worthwhile taking a look at it. Maybe you can try something like the follwing:

```
<div class="cut-off">
    <p class="text">Simple text</p>
</div>​

 .cut-off{
    position: relative;
    width: 300px;
    height: 150px;
    border: 1px solid #7A7764;
    border-radius: 0 75px 0 0;

}

.text {
    margin: 15px;
}
```

​

Comment: sorry, but i don't want rounded corners. I want them to be straight cut offs. See the added picture.

Comment: I see. I think I found something quite more relevant. Take a look at my new answer (code is too big for a comment)